# C++ indexing syntax: two libraries use different indexing syntax: 0 based and 1 based index

Tags: c++, math, dll, matrix-indexing

As shown in the following figure, I have two libraries in my C++ code which use different indexing syntax, one starting with 0 another starting with 1. The C++ code is pretty sophisticated and this difference is very troublesome for me. I was wondering if anybody ran into this trouble before, and if there is a trick for this. I don't know, for example is there a trick to make them have the same indexing syntax!!?

[image]

[image]

I sloved the problem with something like this:

```
#define KFULL(row,col) kFull(row+1,col+1)
    AG_Matrix kFull(4,4,5.0);
    std::cout<<kFull(1,1)<<'\n';//prints 5
    std::cout<<kFull(0,0)<<'\n';//prints garbage value
    std::cout<<KFULL(0,0)<<'\n';//prints 5
    int i=int(0);int j=int(0);
    std::cout<<KFULL(i,j)<<'\n';//prints 5
```

Therefore every time I declare an object of `AG_Matrix` class, I also define a macro for that object to take care of the issue of 0-based and 1-based indexing. This solution was suggested by one of the guys below which simply worked.

Comment: This has nothing to do with syntax. Its a choice the library developers made, and there is really not much you can do about it. Aside from wrapping them yourself to give them consisten behavior wrt 0 or 1 based indexing.

Comment: The real solution would be to remove the use of the 1-based matrix class from the code as much as possible.

Comment: @DDrmmr Currently, I have to use both 0-based and 1-based libraries. But gradually I'm going to get rid of one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad hack

```
#define KFULL(row, column) KFull(row + 1, column + 1)

KFULL(0, 0) = 4.0
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation please? Answers with only code are not so helpful.

Comment: We defined a macro, that increase your indexes. Line KFULL(0, 0) after preprocessing will look like KFull(0 + 1, 0 + 1). P.S. sorry for my english, i'm learning.

Comment: @Kastaneda I tested your suggestion, it worked! 

`#define KFULL(row,col) kFull(row+1,col+1)

AG_Matrix kFull(4,4,5.0);
 
std::cout<<kFull(1,1)<<'\n';//prints 5
 
std::cout<<kFull(0,0)<<'\n';//prints garbage value

 std::cout<<KFULL(0,0)<<'\n';//prints 5

 int i=int(0);int j=int(0);

 std::cout<<KFULL(i,j)<<'\n';//prints 5
`

Answer (score 1):

It'd be best to modify the code of `AG_Matrix` to behave the way you want it. This has the lowest overhead in the generated code.

A workaround would be to derive from `AG_Matrix` and reimplement `operator()(int,int)`. You'd then use the derived class instead of `AG_Matrix`, and it could be used in place of `AG_Matrix` when passed to other code that expects an `AG_Matrix`.

Comment: Thanks. The `AG_Matrix` class is implemented inside a DLL, I don't have the source code. I'm wondering if I can still implement a derived class for the `AG_Matrix` class.

Comment: @user3853917 Sure. It's not relevant where it's implemented. In any case, if that matrix class is any good, most of its implementation is in the header file anyway - certainly the indexing operations are (just look at the header).